# MVC insert error in oracle pl/sql

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oracle, entity-framework

When I add an entity to the database in an MVC project I get this error:

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T84Li.png)

This is the connection string:

```
 <add name="Entities11" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.EasyDocDB.csdl|res://*/Models.EasyDocDB.ssdl|res://*/Models.EasyDocDB.msl;provider=Oracle.DataAccess.Client;provider connection string=&quot;DATA SOURCE=XXXXX;PASSWORD=XXXX;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=XXXX" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Problem:

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 132.

Comment: Seems you're using Entity Framework connection string, are you sure it's right? I think your entity requires Oracle connection string to communicate with DB instead.

Comment: send appconfig or webconfig. Oracle with entityframework you need some tags for Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client